# Android app to display real-time app-specific data transfer statistics

Tags: android, statistics, data-transfer, real-time

Please recommend an Android app that will display real-time app-specific data transfer statistics (amounts uploaded and downloaded).

Requirements:

- Continually updated in real time
- Separates amounts downloaded and uploaded
- Separates each app
- Formatted to make the statistics clear
- Does not slow down data transfer or the device

Not a requirement:

- Does not need to always run in the background.  Can be manually launched.

What I've tried:

- Using Google Play Store search to find such an app.  The search results are fairly useless, as there are so many apps that sort of do this, but not exactly.
- Tried the *Bytes Insight* app.  It is excellent, and makes the statistics available through the notifications.  The downside of it is that as it refreshes the data, the large notification collapses itself.  The makes it very difficult to actually view the data as the user has to repeatedly expand the notification as it collapses.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a case for **[Netlive](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.richardlucasapps.netlive)**:

> NetLive allows you to monitor your internet data transfer rate while displaying which app is currently using the most data. NetLive runs in the notification drawer or as a widget, giving you uninterrupted access to your transfer rate information.

[image: Netlive] [image: Netlive]
<sup>*NetLive* (source: [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.richardlucasapps.netlive); click images for larger variants)</sup>

- **Continually updated in real time:** Yes. You can configure the interval.
- **Separates amounts downloaded and uploaded:** Yes, see screenshots above.
- **Separates each app:** Yes – at least it says so, and the screenshots suggest that.
- **Formatted to make the statistics clear:** Formatted yes, but it's just a "live view" – so no accumulated data
- **Does not slow down data transfer or the device:** Not having tried it myself, I cannot guarantee that – but I doubt it would.
- **Does not need to always run in the background. Can be manually launched.** Being a widget (or a service displaying in the notification area), it must be permanently running.

This app is open source, so no cost involved. Further details:

- [NetLive for Android highlights all apps bandwidth using apps in realtime](http://www.ghacks.net/2013/08/23/netlive-android-highlights-apps-bandwidth-using-apps-realtime/) (GHacks, 8/2013)
- [Youtube Screencast](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vEHPQdu3q90) (2/2014)

Comment: Interesting app, thanks. Unfortunately, it shows the RATE of transfer, and not the QUANTITY.  It also seems to only show the rate of one app at a time, which makes it hard to use.  Looked promising though.

Comment: Oh – sorry, missed that with rate vs. quantity, and wasn't sure how far it might be configurable. Am not aware of any app exactly matching your requirements, but if you want to you can check [my list of stats apps here](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_contacts_statistics#group_93).

Comment: Oh, and btw: Just setting up a new group for [Network Monitoring](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_admin_diagnosis#group_1006) :)